# Submit page limited in time to upload image

Tags: plugins, uploads, forms

I’m not sure where to ask this and where to start to search for this kind of information. Excuses in advance if this is not the right place.

I’m now the admin of a site done with Wordpress for and photographic association. They want to implement a page where registered users can upload one and only one image. After the image is uploaded it must be displayed on the same page next to all other uploaded images from other users.

We have following requirements:

  Image size must be specific (some specific pixels) and we want to validate it before submitting the image.

  The submit possibility must be limited in time (for example, users can only submit photos until 31 December at 12:00AM).

Somebody knows if there is some plugin or how we can archive this or where can I begin to search for information about how to do it?

I’m and experienced Rails developer and have already worked in the past on some Symfony sites with PHP but I’m new in Wordpress development and really don’t know how to do it using this framework/CRM.

I’m considering doing a separate web application developed in Symfony only for this functionality in a subdomain, but before doing it I will explore if they are other possibilities because we have already all other pages in Wordpress.

Comment: About image file dimensions, you can use solution from the question (based on javascript with jQuery): https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904008/4140098

About the time, you can check time / date with php and after that you can hide button or hide page.

Comment: both can be done in js